# ./odoo-bin --config=' /etc/odoo.conf' ODOO 11

Tags: odoo-11

Traceback (most recent call last):
  `File "./odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    import odoo
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/__init__.py", line 88, in <module>
    from . import service
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import wsgi_server
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 25, in <module>
    import werkzeug.contrib.fixers`
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.contrib'

Comment: This issue suddenly happened recently if you install odoo 11 through script, I guess something wrong in source lib werkzeug. I have same issue this morning, and I found there were similar issue in other forums.  [link](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/no-module-named-werkzeug-contrib-164288)

Answer (score 0):

After tracing back errors, I got this error.

`Failed building wheel for pyldap`

And after I run this code.

`sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev`

and

`pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Make sure your werkzeug version in requirements.txt is 0.11.15.
If not 'pip3 install werkzeug==0.11.15'

then you can execute odoo

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when trying to use `Proxyfix` in `werkzeug==1.0.0`

Since that `Werkzeug 1.0.0` has removed deprecated code from `werkzeug.contrib`, `ProxyFix` was relocated to `werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix`

To fix the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.contrib'` Error:

You should import `ProxyFix` with the following code:

```
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
```

I hope this helps and fix your issues